# (Tkinter - Buttons) ¿Cómo creo múltiples objetos con un mismo botón?

Tags: funciones, tkinter, botón, canvas, click

Estoy trabajando en un código que cambia el color de una serie de objetos, que forman una malla, en forma de un degradado entre dos colores en dirección radial. Este cambio ocurre cuando se agrega otro objeto (bola).

Me gustaría que se pudieran agregar tantas bolas como número de objetos en la malla, para esto se me ocurrió definir otro objeto bola en la función `ball_in_plate` para cuando la bola haya sido colocada en la malla; y usar, en esa misma parte del código, `button.config(state = tk.NORMAL)`. Pero cuando lo hago obtengo dos errores: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'` y `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (4,).`

```
import tkinter
import numpy as np
import math
    
#Función para añadir la bola.
def add_ball():
    canvas.bind('<Motion>', locate_ball)
    canvas.bind('<Button-1>', place_ball)

#Función para obtener continuamente la posición de la bola.
def locate_ball(event):
    canvas.coords(ball,
        eventxy+-ball_radius)

#Función para colocar la bola.
def place_ball(event):
    canvas.unbind("<Motion>")
    ballcoords=canvas.coords(ball)
    ball_in_plate(ballcoords)

#Función para obtener los códigos de color.
def compute_colors(startcolor, endcolor, limit):
    (r1,g1,b1) = window.winfo_rgb(startcolor)
    (r2,g2,b2) = window.winfo_rgb(endcolor)
    colors = []
    for i in range(limit):
        colors.append(color)
    return colors    

#Función para animar la malla.
def ball_in_plate(ballcoords):
    for i in range(len(plate)):
        for j in range(len(plate[0])):
            #Cálculo de la distancia de la bola a cada uno de los objetos de la malla.
            dist=math.sqrt((centerball.x - centermeshij.x)**2 + (centerball.y - centermeshij.y)**2)
            #Se considera el escenario donde la bola está cerca de algún objeto.
            if dist <= 25:
                canvas.delete("ball")
                #Cálculo del gradiente de color.
                color = compute_colors("yellow2", "grey", 2)
                #Se configura el patrón del gradiente en dirección radial.
                for o in range(len(plate)):
                    for p in range(len(plate[0])):
                        dis = math.sqrt((centermeshij.x - centermeshop.x)**2 + (centermeshij.y - centermeshop.y)**2)
                        if dis <= 100:
                            canvas.itemconfig(mesh[o][p], fill=color[0])
                        else:
                            canvas.itemconfig(mesh[o][p], fill=color[1])
                #Se configura este elemento para indicar que la bola ha sido colocada.
                canvas.itemconfig(mesh[i][j], fill="yellow", outline="green", tag="placedball")
                return
            #Se considera el otro escenario.
            else: 
                pass
    
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Mesh simulation")
window.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}')
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window)
canvas.configure(bg="black")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
mesh=np.zeros([12, 17], dtype=np.uint32)
#Malla de objetos
for i in range (0, 1250, 78):
    for j in range (0, 690, 62):
        mesh[j//62, i//78]=canvas.create_oval(i+5,j+5,i+30,j+30,fill="grey", outline="white", width=2, tag="mesh")
ball = canvas.create_oval(0,0,0,0,fill="yellow", outline="white", width=2, tag="ball")
button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Add ball", command=add_ball).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es haber definido el objeto bola de manera general, pues después de la acción del botón se elimina y ya no se puede volver a usar.

Crear ese objeto múltiples veces se puede conseguir definiendo una función que lo haga de manera global (para que pueda ser llamado por las demás funciones):

```
def create_ball():
    global ball
    ball = canvas.create_oval(0,0,0,0, fill="yellow", outline="white", width=2, tag="ball")
    add_ball()
```

Y después ligarla al botón:

```
button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Add ball", command=create_ball)
button.pack()
```

Sin embargo, el efecto de esto se verá parcialmente anulado por la línea `canvas.itemconfig(mesh[i][j], fill="yellow", outline="green", tag="placedball")` en `placed_ball`.